# Could You please help me prove this statement about continuous functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-explanation

Could You please help me prove this statement?
$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the limit of continuous functions if and if only there exist $g: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ partial continuous function so that $f(x) = g(x,x)$.

Comment: Hint:$g(x,y)=f(x)(x-y+1)$

Comment: Thank You Eureka. Using your advice I can see if g is partial continuous then f must be continuous too. If f is continuous, than it must be the limit of continuous functions. But how does being the limit of continuos functions implicate that there is an
appropriate g?